# Cannot get my cmd out of fullscreen

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-terminal

I changed the default settings for my command prompts to full screen for a test but have been able to get them out of it. I have tried every variation of Alt-Enter I could find but they all just changed the size of the window and never revealed the tab section. Apart from going through the tab section I have found no way to access the command prompt settings and remove the full screen which appears to be the only way to do so permenantly. Some of the projects I am working on rely on a certain window size so keeping it like this is not an option.

Comment: Are you using the newer windows terminal or older conhost?  I am mostly sure that the settings are stored differently and whoever helps you will need this information.

Comment: Also, what did you use to make it fullscreen?

Comment: I am using the windows terminal and right clicked on it's tab area to get to setting where I changed the default size setting to fullscreen

Comment: You can't just Winkey+Tab and then right-click it?

Comment: Nope, I can snap it to the left and right but that doesn't shift it out of fullscreen

Comment: Even though I posted an answer, I really recommend switching to something like ConEmu or at least trying something else out. Windows Terminal is... awful. Every time I launch it I find a new bug. This time my window started in German language for no reason (not the system language or something I set up) and also saving/discarding settings in fullscreen doesn't close the tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exit the mode temporarily

If you want to exit it just temporarily, then the default keybind is also more or less classic <kbd>F11</kbd>. You can rebind it in settings.

There are 2 ways to make it start not in fullscreen again.

### Enter settings with default hotkey

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) by default allows you to enter the settings view also in fullscreen mode. There you can change <kbd>Launch mode</kbd> setting to any other value, e.g. `Default`.

### Edit .json file

Open this file:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_[version_hash]\LocalState\settings.json
```

Find:

```
"launchMode": "fullscreen"
```

and change it to:

```
"launchMode": "default"
```

Comment: Thank you so much the Ctrl + , worked magically!